# Success response even if phone is not switched on?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing in Android Studio. I am sending a message to a phone using the gcm api. When my emulator phone is switched off, or even when Android Studio is not running, I seem to still get the same 200 response as when it is working:

```
{
  "multicast_id": 7720588456407474000,
  "success": 1,
  "failure": 0,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "message_id": "0:1506588867554395%84af3a08f9fd7ecd"
    }
   ]
}
```

How can I know that my message is not received?

Comment: Response `"success": count` is if notification was received by server, validated and sent to device, not received by device.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin :-)

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response `"success": count` is to determine if notification was received by server, validated and sent to device, not received by device.

Comment: What does "sent to device" mean? If device does not have an address because it is switched off, then how can server send?  If server is **unable to send** because the whereabouts of device is not known does it still count as **sent**?

Comment: Device is registred in FCM using a registration id. So sending a to device is made using that id. Also could be sent to a topic or specific range of devices (android or ios only).